# Marshmallow crash in tgkill

Tags: android, crash, version, native

This crash just occurs on Android API 23 or version 6.0, and I don't have any idea how to fix this issue?

Here's the crash report :

```
  #00  pc 000000000006ab74  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
  #01  pc 0000000000068304  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+68)
  #02  pc 00000000000212f8  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+28)
  #03  pc 000000000001ba98  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+60)
  #04  pc 0000000000435798  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+324)
  #05  pc 0000000000139264  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+3136)
  #06  pc 00000000003109cc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+2084)
  #07  pc 0000000000310f68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+224)
  #08  pc 0000000000351ca4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI15CallVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+616)
  #09  pc 00000000000963cc  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
  #10  pc 0000000073b78ba4  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat
```

It happened when using support library 26.x.x , Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Facing the same issue, Is there any solution?

Comment: I use AndroidX library and have same crashes in my console. Also have it for Android 7.0